# How can I merge two Handlebars partials before running them through Assemble 0.6.0?

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

I have two .hbs files. One contains a basic button and the other contains a button bar that utilizes that {{basic-button}}. I want to pull the first .hbs into the second and then have Assemble render it as a file.

I thought it was as easy as registering the basic-button as a partial and passing it to the button bar page. But it looks like I need to run through my .hbs files, render them and then let assemble do its thing.

Is there an equivalent of handlebars.registerpartials i can use in Assemble

Answer (score 1):

You can register partials with the `.partials` method...

```
assemble.partials(['partials/*.hbs']);
```

Then you can use those partials with normal handlebars syntax (use the filename as the partial name)

```
{{> basic-button}}
```

If this isn't what you're looking to do, could you post a repository that I could look at?

**Edit**

Based on the comments: You can use layouts inside partials (and other template types)

*element partials*

```
---
layout: button-bar
---
{{> basic-button }}
```

*button-bar*

```
{% body %}
```

But I don't think that's what you're trying to accomplish because you probably want multiple "basic-button" partials inside the button bar.

Another option is to use front-matter inside your page to specify the list of buttons and pass it to the partial as the partial's context:

*page.hbs*

```
---
buttons:
 - "basic-button"
 - "advanced-button"
 - "menu-button"
---
{{> button-bar buttons}}
```

Then inside `button-bar` you can use our built in `partial` helper to dynamically include the partials from the list:

```
<ul class="btn-bar">
{{#each this}}
  <li class="btn">{{partial this}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Hope this helps some.

Comment: I have two levels of code fragments. Simple and complex. Before I wrap anything w/ assemble I want the Complex pages (referencing the simple fragments as partials) to compile. So "pre-hbs" compiling prior to handing it off for Assemble.

i have it working with:
```gulp.task('pre', function () {
    return gulp
        .src('./src/blocks/header-bar/*.hbs')
        .pipe(hb({
            partials: './src/elements/**/*.hbs',
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/hbs/'));
});
```
but figured there had to be a way to do it with Assemble. Sadly, I can't share the repo.

Comment: Sorry I missed your comment on this... in assemble 0.6.0+ we support layouts in all template types (including partials). I'll update the answer with an example since it won't fit in the comment.